# Nodejs, Mongoose, Jquery widget

Tags: node.js, widget, mongoose

Hi i was wondering if there is a module for nodejs which allows for simplistic widget creation in combination with mongoose as a datasource to create nice JQuery library (such as dojo or YUI) widgets.

for example when i setup my schema it would be nice to do something like (note code not runnable just pseudo)

```
var carSchema = {
  carname: "String",
  registration: "String",
  mileage: "Number"}

methodCallback  = function() {
  car.find({}, ....) {
    return results;
  }
}

model.register("car", carSchema);

res.send(model.createWidget("listview", options, methodCallback()));
```

where createWidgets returns the html list view code and paging for the cars from the result i return in my callback. it would be nice if it integrated with REST so if i delete an item from the listview then it actions this on a connection to another method.

basically i want to try and remove all the difficulty of populating, deleting, updating, a widget on client side development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "remove all the difficulty of populating, deleting, updating, a widget on client side development."

seems not very realistic as you always have to specify some specific CURD logic based on your needs.

For pure front end part, you may try AngularJS, which provide easy to use RESTful CURD service http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

if you are into more giant framework of full stack javascript (may not be Nodejs, Mongoose, Jquery widget), wakanda http://www.wakanda.org/features/studio may have something you are looking for as provide some widget integration with datasource.

Comment: its not too unrealistic as i have seen something similar with smartGWT buts its java,

I have looked at angular real quick, sort of does what I want, but it looks a bit limited.

Infact I am using Mojito to create the crud (as you said) and using YUI to generate the javascript widgets client side, its not as automatic as i hoped, but reduces maintenance effort quite a bit.

Comment: http://www.jroller.com/sjivan/entry/smartgwt_1_0_released here is a description of smart gwt - if no one improves on your answer I will mark it as answered as it sort of does what I asked, thanks